# Auto hiding navigation at bottom of browser window

Tags: jquery, navigation

having a problem getting my navigation div properly autohiding.

What I want to happen is this:

By default my navigation is hidden.

Either when a user clicks a link OR a user mouses near the bottom of the browser window, the navigation will appear(slide up). My navigation is in a div with an id of "tS2".
When the user mouses off of the navigation div, the navigation will hide(slide down) after a short delay.

I have the mouse position script correctly working

```
$(document).mousemove(function(ev){
 var ev = ev || window.event;
 //console.log('Mouse y ='+ev.pageY);
 if(ev.pageY>(_windowHeight-120)){
    console.log('YES triggered show nav!');
    showNav(true,1000)
 }
```

});

And this is my shownav function which works correctly on document load.
But when I call showNav(true,1000) the navigation jumps immediately into view instead of gradually over 1 second(my duration). Can anyone spot my error?

```
function showNav(bflag,dur,delay){
if(bflag===true){
    $("#tS2").stop(true,true).animate({
                'bottom':'0'
            }, dur);
}else{
    $("#tS2").stop(true,true).animate({
                'bottom':'-125px'
            }, dur);
}
}

showNav(false,1000);
```

Comment: I would need to see a real example to determine for sure, but I wonder if the problem has to do with the method/manner in which your html/css is structured to hide the item in the first place.  Does the code exist somewhere that can be viewed, or could you include the html/css sub-set involved?

Comment: Thanks for the great replies. Part of the problem may be in how I am positioning the the nav at the bottom of the browser window. If I can't solve it with the answers supplied, will post my complete code online.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description I put together this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zPs4G/3/

Try it :)

Comment: That's a nice solution to the design problem, but doesn't really debug the coding issue eco_bach asked about.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a lot of details, but it sounds like you want the navigation to do something like this:

```
$('#tS2').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Put this in place of your console.log and I think you are almost done. You just need a corresponding if statement to trigger the mouse out event, but you already know how to do that.